# how to pass data to mixins and then displaying them in your component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, mixins

I want to pass data to my mixin's method, and then display it in my component. Something like:

```
//component A

mixins: [mixinOne],
data(){
  return{
    val = null
  }
},
mounted(){
  this.mixinMethod('good value', this.val);
}
```

```
//mixinOne
mixinMethod(valOne, valTwo) {
  valTwo = valOne;
}
```

And in my template I want to display val:

```
// component A
<template>
  {{val}}
</template>
```

I have written the above code and it doesn't work. It returns null for `{{val}}`! So basically I want to see 'good value' in my component for `{{val}}` which is setup through my mixin. How can I do that?

Comment: On top of the answer that was given to you, you do have this part of the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Basics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Should put your Data section in mixin then change it and render it in your component.

```
// MmixinOne
data () {
  return {
    val = null
  }
},
methods: {
  mixinMethod (valOne, valTwo) {
     valTwo = valOne
  }
}

// Component A
<template>
  {{val}}
</template>

<script>
import MmixinOne from './MmixinOne'

export default {
  mixins: [MmixinOne],
  mounted () {
    this.mixinMethod('good value', this.val)
  }
}
</script>
```

Anyway you dont need a method to set value on "val".
you can just set your value directly in mounted:

```
mounted () {
  this.val = 'good value'
}
```